# Google Embed API Chart Types?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

I am trying to use the Embed API to make a custom dashboard from my Google Analytics account.

Below, you will see the code that is used to render the chart on the screen.  Inside of the `chart` object, there is a property called `type` which is set to `LINE` in the example below.

Where can I find a list of these values?  It's really annoying having to arbitrarily guess what the string values are.  The documentation doesn't show what the possible values are or how many there are.

I tried going to the Goolge Charts page and look for a list, but I couldn't find it either.  Any help is appreciated.

```
var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    query: {
      metrics: 'ga:sessions,ga:uniquePageviews',
      dimensions: 'ga:date',
      'start-date': '10daysAgo',
      'end-date': 'yesterday'
    },
    chart: {
      container: 'chart-container',
      type: 'LINE',
      options: {
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check [Built-in Components Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference) of Embed API and checkout the [Datachart Options](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference#datachart-options).

Following are the chart types:

- LINE
- COLUMN
- BAR
- TABLE
- GEO

Comment: Thanks!  That documentation sucks.

Answer (score 2):

There is an additional chart type of `PIE`. This is not mentioned in the official documentation. [Here is a demo of the `PIE` type](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/multiple-views/).

Comment: I find it absolutely baffling how Google can forget to add details like this in something that is so widely used!